# Datatable malfunction on chrome

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have an issue with Datatable plug-in for jQuery and Google Chrome. Datatable plug-in works correctly with firefox.
I have two datatable on same page, the first datatable is ok but the second does not display correctly only with Chrome. I haven't an error in the console.

On Google Chrome :

[Capture Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmIed.png)

On Firefox :

[Capture Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CDRL.png)

Jquery code for datatable that doesn't work :

```
$('#datatable_piece').dataTable({
    "sDom": '<"row"<"col-sm-8"l><"col-sm-4"f>>t<"row"<"col-sm-5">rp>',
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    "bSort": true,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ entrées ",
        "sInfoFiltered" : " - filtré de _MAX_ entrées",
        "sSearch": "Rechercher : ",
        "sZeroRecords": "Pas d'entrées à montrer",
        "sEmptyTable": "La table ne contient pas de données",
        "sInfo": "_START_ à _END_  entrées (Total de _TOTAL_ entrées)",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Veuillez attendre - Chargement...",
        "sProcessing": "L'application est actuellement occupée"},
    "bServerSide": false,
    "aaSorting": false,
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 15, 20, 50, 100, 150, -1],
        [10, 15, 20, 50, 100, 150, "Tout"]
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
});
```

Comment: Add some relevant code of datatable which you are using and check for any console error in chrome